# Как указать отношения между моделями в Веб-API ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: postgresql, api, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Я начал изучать ASP.NET ,

по примеру из этого сайта

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/asp-dotnet-core-crud-web-api-dapper-postgresql.aspx

я смог подключить postgresql

я создал модель Project

```
 public class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AdminUser { get; set; }
        public int ProjectManager { get; set; }
        public List<int> Users { get; set; }
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Также я создал для него сервис

```
 public async Task<bool> CreateProject(Project project)
        {
            var result =
                        await _dbService.EditData(
        "INSERT INTO public.projects (id,adminuserid, projectmanagerid, name) VALUES (@Id, @AdminUser, @ProjectManager, @Name)",
        project);
            return true;

        
        }
```

Все работает корректно, но мне надо создать отношение многие ко многим между Project и User
В моей базе данных есть таблицы project , user и userproject в котором будут id проекта и id юзера , но я не могу разобраться ,как создать отношения

При запуске проекта в Swagger UI  есть такой Json

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "adminUser": 0,
  "projectManager": 0,
  "users": [
    0
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "description": "string",
      "startTime": "2023-11-28T18:56:20.714Z",
      "endTime": "2023-11-28T18:56:20.714Z",
      "responsibleUser": 0,
      "priority": 0,
      "status": 0
    }
  ],
  "name": "string"
}
```

Помогите разобраться, может мне стоит изменить связи в базе данных? Или я делаю что то не так?